# keyboard should appear when MFMailComposeViewController appear

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using swift for development.I want that When MFMailComposer appear, toReceipt textField should automatically become first responder.

Answer (score 1):

From [MFMailComposeViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html):

> IMPORTANT
>
> The view hierarchy of this class is private and you must not modify
> it. You can, however, customize the appearance of an instance by using
> the UIAppearance protocol.
>
> After presenting a mail comopose view controller, your app cannot
> change the email content. The user can edit the content of a presented
> instance but the system ignores programmatic changes. If you want to
> set values for the content fields, do so before presenting the
> interface.

Comment: You mean it is not possible to set toTextField as first responder.

Comment: Yes it is not possible but if somehow you try to do that then system will ignore that as mentioned in document.

Comment: but doc says about the content only not interaciton

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna set subject, you can set it in your program.

Apple does not allow developer use private API, If you use those API, your APP would be reject by Apple.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[picker setSubject:@"Mail subject"];
[picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email@email.com",nil]];
```